# Show detached digital signatures with PDFRender

Tags: android, pdf, digital-signature, pdfrenderer

I've got a PDF with detached signatures but they are not showing when I render the PDF with PDFRenderer (android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer). Is there any way to show these signatures with PDFRenderer or do I need to use a third party library?

Comment: Does PdfRenderer support PDF Annotations? If it doesn't, you won't see the usual PDF signature visualizations in it. By the way, you say "detached signatures"... do you mean integrated signatures of type "adbe.pkcs7.detached" / "ETSI.CAdES.detached"? Or do you mean literally detached signature files?

Comment: The PDFRenderer does not support PDF Annotations so I guess that answers my question. It is signatures of the type "adbe.pkcs7.detached" that I am trying to open.

Comment: One thing you could do is *flatten* the form fields of the PDF, in particular the signature form fields, before displaying.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any flatten method in either PdfRenderer or the PdfBox-Android library (based on PDFBox 1.8)  that I am using. I ended up rendering any page containing signatures with PDFBox-Android instead of the PdfRenderer. I works but it has some visual flaws.